# My PHP & MySQL script is working perfectly fine locally, but not on my live site

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script on my website which handles a notification system for messages, and alerts. This script pulls in the data from a MySQL Database, and it works like a charm locally, but on my live site, the query fails. This script always returns false and goes to the else condition live, but locally it works exactly the way it should.

```
$queryNots = 'Select message, DATE_FORMAT(timeSent, "%h:%i %p %W, %M %D ") timeSent FROM notifications WHERE UserID="' . $userId . '" AND seen="n";';
if ($result = $con->query ($query)) {
    $resultNum = mysqli_num_rows ( $result );
    echo '<h2>You have ' . $resultNum . ' Notifications</h2>
            <ul>';
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
        echo '<li>' . $row ["message"] . ' @ ' . $row ['timeSent'] . '</li>';
    }
    if ($resultNum > 0) {
        echo '
            </ul>
                <form method="post" action="deleteNots.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="curID" value="' . $userId . '">
                    <input type="submit" value="Dismiss">
                </form>
            ';
    }
} else {
    echo '<h2>Error reading table</h2>';
}
```

On the live site if I take out the if-else and just run the query not only does it fail, it kills the entire script. I have no idea what could be causing this, I know the tables are the same, because I use them in a different script just fine.

I have absolutely nothing to work with, because it isn't giving me any sort of MySQL error message to go off of. I really want to get this figured out because I want to have this site back working as soon as possible.

Comment: try echo mysql_error() to see what´s going on there

Comment: After you initialize `$con` you can `var_dump($con)` does that shows something? Also shouldn't it be `$con->query ($queryNots)`?

Comment: `seen="n";';`  ... ??? what is this ? in your query note .. why use two semi colon ?

Comment: @handsome You have a typo there, need an `i`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: `$queryNots` is never used.

Comment: @Lordbug You are using MySQLi, but why are you not using parameterized queries? Currently, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @handsome Thank You Soooo Much. It says the table doesn't exist, That I can work with. Thank You. Can you make an answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my issue ended up coming in the comments of the question, so I couldn't mark it as completed.

> try echo mysql_error() to see what´s going on there – handsome Jul 29
>   '17 at 14:51

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'Select message, DATE_FORMAT(timeSent, "%h:%i %p %W, %M %D ") timeSent FROM notifications WHERE UserID="' . $userId . '" AND seen="n"';


$result = $con->query($query);

if ($result) {

    $resultNum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo '<h2>You have '.$resultNum.'Notifications</h2><ul>';

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<li>' . $row ["message"] . ' @ ' . $row ['timeSent'] . '</li>';
    }

    if ($resultNum > 0) {
        echo '
            </ul>
                <form method="post" action="deleteNots.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="curID" value="' . $userId . '">
                    <input type="submit" value="Dismiss">
                </form>
            ';
    }
} else {
    echo '<h2>Error reading table</h2>';
}
```

> NOTE:

- Change the `$queryNots` variable because you used the `$query` variable below code 
  i.e:  `$result = $con->query($query);`
- unwanted semicolon(;) in `$queryNots` ::  `seen="n";';`

Comment: Answers should have an explanation, not just `Try This`.

Comment: `queryuNote` is not used and its acutally use the query and `unwanterd` semi colon used in the code that changed .. @chris85

Comment: Rishi, Please mention it in your answer.

Comment: @NanaPartykar okzz

Comment: The `;` wouldn't create an issue so the only change here is removing `Nots` from the variable..

Comment: @chris85 okzzzz

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar When I put the code in as you gave it to me I got the message `Warning: mysqli_num_rows(): Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\loggedIn.php on line 222`

Comment: @Lordbug ...`MYSQL_USE_RESULT` remove it its not required

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Taking that out fixed that error locally, but live it still skips straight to the else clause.